# Yo Meanjs is not installing Angular

Tags: angularjs, meanjs, yo

I am following the steps of installing yo meanjs. When I am done installing yo meanjs, and type grunt it serves to my localhost:3000. When I open the page I don't get the MEAN JS test page. I have mongod running. However I am getting an error that angular isn't installed.

Everything installed but this is the output of an error in my terminal.

```
            throw err;
            ^
```

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/chinenyem/.config/configstore/bower-github.json'
You don't have access to this file.

```
at Error (native)
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:634:18)
at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:502:33)
at Object.create.all.get (/Users/chinenyem/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.2/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/configstore/index.js:35:26)
at Object.Configstore (/Users/chinenyem/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.2/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/configstore/index.js:28:44)
at readCachedConfig (/Users/chinenyem/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.2/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/config.js:19:23)
at defaultConfig (/Users/chinenyem/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.2/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/config.js:11:12)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/chinenyem/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.2/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/index.js:16:32)
at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
```

normalizeTree → install   ▌ ╢░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR

> > Error: Cannot find module 'time-grunt'

Answer (score 0):

You should use
sudo [your command]

Comment: or for quickness `sudo !!`